# Why is my program not properly working for C?

Tags: c

My program is supposed to display in an array how is R1=x, R2=x, R3=x. Then it is supposed to calculate the equivalent resistance of the resistors in series. All the values are user supplied. My problem is that I don't think it passes the function over properly to equivRseries. On the output, it lets me put in the amount of resistors, but once I put in a value for resistance, it won't let me enter the value of the rest of the resistors. Can I please get some help with this? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define max 100

void equivRseries(float R[max], float N, float *xPtr);
void input (float *xPtr, float R[max], float N){
    int i;
    printf("Please enter how many resistors you want in series:   ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("Enter the value of R%d:    ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &R[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("R[%d]=%.2f\n", i+1, *(xPtr+i));
    }
    equivRseries(R, N, xPtr);
}

void equivRseries(float R[max], float N, float *xPtr){
    int i;
    float equivR=0;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        equivR=equivR+*(xPtr+i);
    }
    printf("Equivalent resistance of this circuit is %f\n", equivR);
}

int main(){
    float R[max], series, N;
    float *xPtr;
    xPtr=R;
    input(xPtr,R,N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you discover when you tried debugging the program? Hint: look at `N`.

Comment: why do you have both xPtr and R? You seems to use them the same (i.e. printing "R[%d]" but using *(xPtr+i)

Comment: Seems like a lot of complex code just to add input numbers into an accumulator:(

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
scanf("%d", &N);
```

`N` is of type `float` and so, `&N` is of type `float*`. But `%d` expects an `int*`, not a `float*`. This invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

Fix it by either changing the format specifier to `%f` or by changing the type of `N` to `int`.

---

BTW, it doesn't make sense why you pass `N` to the function instead of declaring it in the function. Also, there is no need for `xPtr`. You can directly use `R` instead of `xPtr`.

---

You would've noticed the problem if you had compiled with warnings (at least with `-Wall`) as [@hexasoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5440452/hexasoft) [has said below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654568/why-is-my-program-not-properly-working-for-c/33654691#comment55082632_33654691). GCC gives:

```
source_file.c: In function ‘input’:
source_file.c:8:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%d", &N);
  ^
```

Comment: And compile with warnings. This kind of problem is printed at compilation stage.

Comment: Yes. Correct. I've added that to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
int input (float *xPtr, float R[max],float N){
    int i;
    printf("Please enter how many resistors you want in series:   ");
    scanf("%f", &N);
    //      ^___________ use "%f" for float
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("Enter the value of R%d:    ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", R+i);
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("R[%d]=%.2f\n", i+1, *(xPtr+i));
    }
    equivRseries(R, N, xPtr);
    return N;
}
```